# Are questions about collecting payment from a client for freelance work on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, questions

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199785/clever-way-to-license-obfuscate-web-applications-until-the-client-has-paid-for-i) is posed in terms of ASP.NET, but (in my opinion) is really about collecting payment. (See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/192138))

Are questions about collecting payment for freelance work on topic? The FAQ lists "freelancing and business concerns" as on-topic, but I would think questions about writing a contract that includes payment collection would be better directed to a lawyer.

Comment: For future reference, a new SE site just appeared where the question in question _might_ be on topic: [Freelancing Stack Exchange](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

That's a general business concern that doesn't pertain to software development specifically.